# Dropzone disable upload

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I wanna know how to disabled upload if i have 1 file has uploaded. But if i remove file, the ddropzone been enabled to upload.

here's my code on js:

```
Dropzone.options.attachmenacc = {
            maxFiles: 1,
            accept: function(file, done) {

            },
            init: function() {
                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                    alert("No more files please!");
                });
            },
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function(file) {
                var name = file.name;        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: host+'upload/bank/unfile',
                    data: "id="+name,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
                var _ref;
                return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;   

                //console.log();
            },          
        }
```

Well on my code now, if i add upload file more, it show alert, and these file (expected first file) wont uploaded, but it still show that file was uploaded.